# how to update /etc/resolv.conf in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, resolv.conf

I have made changes to "/etc/reslov.conf" and want to changes to take effect. I tried following this but still no effect

```
$ sudo su
sudo: unable to resolve host accretive-new32GB-ephimeral-new
root@accretive-new32GB-ephimeral-new:/home/ubuntu# /etc/init.d/networking restart
root@accretive-new32GB-ephimeral-new:/home/ubuntu# exit
ubuntu@accretive-new32GB-ephimeral-new:~$ sudo su
sudo: unable to resolve host accretive-new32GB-ephimeral-new
root@accretive-new32GB-ephimeral-new:/home/ubuntu# resolvconf -u
root@accretive-new32GB-ephimeral-new:/home/ubuntu# exit
ubuntu@accretive-new32GB-ephimeral-new:~$ sudo su
sudo: unable to resolve host accretive-new32GB-ephimeral-new
root@accretive-new32GB-ephimeral-new:/home/ubuntu# service resolvconf restart
resolvconf stop/waiting
resolvconf start/running
root@accretive-new32GB-ephimeral-new:/home/ubuntu# exit
ubuntu@accretive-new32GB-ephimeral-new:~$ sudo su
sudo: unable to resolve host accretive-new32GB-ephimeral-new
root@accretive-new32GB-ephimeral-new:/home/ubuntu#
```

Changes to reslov.conf :

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: You can run commands directly with `sudo` instead of using `sudo su` to get a root shell. Example: `sudo resolvconf -u`.

Comment: # cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

nameserver 8.8.8.8

Comment: As indicated by the file's comment section, you should NOT edit it by hand if your system uses `resolvconf`. Instead, you should add the desired nameserver(s) via the nm-applet GUI (if you are using a desktop system, with network-manager) or via the /etc/network/interfaces file (if you are using a server, with ifupdown).